# Use Variable As Column Header in SUMMARIZECOLUMNS

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am attempting to dynamically name a column using SUMMARIZECOLUMNS and variables.

This code works, and I can tell that the variables are returning correctly. However, when I try to replace the text between the quotes in SUMMARIZECOLUMNS with the string variables, I get an error:

```
Calculate Table = 
VAR _today =
    TODAY ()
VAR _2Year =
    YEAR ( _today ) - 2
VAR _2YearString =
    CONVERT ( _2Year, STRING )
VAR _1Year =
    YEAR ( _today ) - 1
VAR _1YearString =
    CONVERT ( _1Year, STRING )
RETURN
    SUMMARIZECOLUMNS (
        'Final Table'[Category],
        "FY2020", CALCULATE ( SUM ( 'Final Table'[Value] ), 'Date Table'[Year] = _2Year ),
        "FY2021", CALCULATE ( SUM ( 'Final Table'[Value] ), 'Date Table'[Year] = _1Year )
    )
```

[image]

I would really like to dynamically name these columns so that when the next fiscal year rolls around, I don't have to update the DAX string in the header from "FY2020" to "FY2021".

Here's a [link to the .pbix in Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rmyIZotbSkXwCxa8GdbrC9K5-MoT5Y4N/view?usp=share_link).

Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You are on a wrong path. There is no need for this calculated table, simply use measures.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, and if you look at the .pbix you'll see there are also measures. However, even with a measure, you can't dynamically name it.

Comment: I looked at your pbix. My point is different: your overall approach is wrong. Don't create any calculated tables, at all. Just use fiscal year attribute from the date table to create the desired report.

Comment: Variables can't be used to name calc. column names!